# Why the converted videos file size is greater than original file size?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to convert the videos into mp4.Its working fine  and its playing with high quality.No problem.But the worst case is I uploaded 14Mb file and after converting it goes to 30 Mb file.I am using the following the script to convert

```
exec("ffmpeg -i videowithaudio.flv -vcodec libx264 -vpre hq -vpre ipod640 -b 250k -bt 50k -acodec libfaac -ab 56k -ac 2 -s 480x320 video_out_file.mp4 > output1.txt 2> apperror1.txt");   //webkit compatible
```

I am using PHP for executing this command.Could you please help me how to reduce the file size from this 30Mb (nearly to uploaded file size is ok) with same quality.

Comment: You may get more focused answers on the site for AV questions at http://avp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The only thing I can assure you with, is that PHP has absolutely nothing to do here

Answer (score 1):

Files converted from `flv` to `mp4` will always have greater size than the source file. Generally flv files are smaller than other formats, thats why youtube converts all files to flv.

you can use `-sameq` parameter to retain the quality of video and lesser file size of resulting output file.

Example 1:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -sameq -ar 22050 output.mp4
```

Example 2:

```
exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i input.flv -acodec libfaac -sameq -ar 44100 -ab 96k -coder ac -me_range 16 -subq 5 -sc_threshold 40 -b 1600k -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -i_qfactor 0.71 -keyint_min 25 -b_strategy 1 -g 250 -r 20 output.mp4");
```

I created this command by searching alot and this fulfills my requirements, using this you can get a bit less file size but with same quality.

Hope this works for you also.

Comment: Thanks for the information you provided here.That makes the sense.But what you gave is make the file size more than previous one 30Mb to 40MB.So I cant take this one.Sorry!

Comment: I didn't asked you to use this command as it is, just remove the parameters which you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You should try playing around with your key frames rate (-g). Frames between key frames have only the pixels different from the previous key frame. If your key frames are too far apart, all pixels are present in middle frames (increasing size), too close and the number of key frames increases the file size.

Note that the optimal key frame rate will be different for each video, so you need to find a middle ground.

Answer (score 0):

```
exec("ffmpeg -i videowithaudio.flv -vcodec libx264 -vpre hq -vpre ipod640 -b 250k -bt 50k -acodec libfaac -ab 56k -ac 2 -s 480x320 video_out_file.mp4 > output1.txt 2> apperror1.txt");   //webkit compatible
```

Important for the filesize, is the [bitrate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_rate). The bitrate specifies how many bytes to use per second video. If you decrease the bitrate, the filesize will also become smaller.

You are currently using 250kbit/s video (`-b 250k`) and 56kbit/s audio (`-ab 56k`), so you have to decrease those numbers. For example you can try :`-b 100k -ab 32k`. But keep in mind that the quality will also decrease when you decrease the bitrate. If the quality becomes too bad, you can also decrease the framerate or frame size to increase the quality.